# Need help getting network shares to mount on boot with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, mount, fstab

I have all my movies and music on my WD MyCloudpr4100. I got my hands on an old Dell Poweredge 1950 that I plan on using for a Plex server. I want to have my folders on the network storage to auto mount when I reboot the server. Plex also wants them to be mounted as a local drive which I can do but it will only stay mounted until reboot. I have tried multiple times to edit the fstab file to get them to mount.  But when I save the file and go mount –a I get errors and it does not mount the folder. If I remove the last line in fstab and save everything works fine. I really need help to get this to happen.

Comment: "I get errors" is not really helpful for us. Which errors exactly? Please modify your question to include the errors that you receive.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the mount lines that don't work and the errors that you received.

Comment: Sorry guys i was not sitting infront of the system when writing this. After trying the mounting directions if there is still errors i will post them.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably mount it using the CIFS Utils and add it to your `/etc/fstab` file.

Install the `cifs-utils`

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
```

Then give your NAS device a mount point

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/NAS
```

Then add a line to your `/etc/fstab` file so that every time it reboots it will mount it automatically.  The line would look something like the following:

```
//10.0.0.220/storage    /media/NAS  cifs    guest,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm,nofail 0   0
```

Make sure to replace the `//10.0.0.220/storage` with whatever the share is on the device.  Once that is added, you can then just run `sudo mount -a` to mount it without the need of a reboot.

Comment: This is a little different from what i had found to try. I will try this tonight when i get home. thank you